# ROS Noetic Install Wiki Page Enhancement

Tags: ros, rosdep, wiki, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I noticed that the ROS Noetic install wiki page at http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu does not include the section titled 'Dependencies for building packages' as previous ROS distros did. As a result, new ROS developers might not realize that they need to install tools like python3-rosdep, build-essential, along with other handy python packages. Then when they try to run rosdep, they don't understand why packages are failing to be installed correctly. I think it's even more imperative to include this section especially because many of these packages have slightly different names (that include a '3' for Python3).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369487/ros-noetic-install-wiki-page-enhancement/) by [swiz23](https://answers.ros.org/users/52899/swiz23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2021-01-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2021-01-13**:
You are able to edit this yourself if you like! If you make a ROS wiki account you can edit pages to reflect that change :-)

**Comment by [swiz23](https://answers.ros.org/users/52899/swiz23/) on 2021-01-15**:
Thanks @stevemacenski,

I didn't realize that anyone could edit the ROS Wiki pages. I'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @stevemacenski mentioned, I was able to make the necessary edits by creating a Wiki account and editing the page directly.

---

Originally posted by [swiz23](https://answers.ros.org/users/52899/swiz23/) with karma: 86 on 2021-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-20**:
Diff [here](http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu?action=diff&rev2=7&rev1=6).